# Casting a primitive type to T (which is also primitive) is Rust

Tags: rust

as I have a problem with casting primitive type (usize) to T.

Now I have something like this:

```
fn calculate_center_of_points(points: &Vec<point::Point<T>>) -> Option<point::Point<T>>
{
    if points.len() == 0
    {
        return None
    }
    let tmp: T = Default::default();
    let mut pointCount : T = Default::default();
    let mut center_point = point::Point::new(tmp, tmp);
    for p in points
    {
        center_point.move_point(p.x,p.y);
        pointCount = pointCount + T::one();
    }
    let center_point = point::Point::new(center_point.x / pointCount, center_point.y / pointCount);
    Some(center_point)
}
```

but I would like to achive something like

```
for p in points
    {
        center_point.move_point(p.x,p.y);
        pointCount = pointCount + T::one();
    }
    let center_point = point::Point::new(center_point.x / points.len() as T, center_point.y / points.len() as T);
```

I already looked up the num crate, but I couldn't find something that I would like to use in my "good" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `num` crate has a [`FromPrimitive`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/cast/trait.FromPrimitive.html) trait which looks like what you want.

So you'd use it like:

```
use num::FromPrimitive;

fn get_len<T:FromPrimitive>(v: Vec<T>) -> Option<T> {
    T::from_usize(v.len())
}
```

And any `T` would obviously need to implement `FromPrimitive`; according to the documentation it comes with implementations for the primitive number types and `BigInt`/`BigUint`.